# How to implement language switcher by subdomains MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

How can I implement solution, where language switcher won't be consisted on session variables or `xyz.com/{language}` parameters in URL (I have that approach now).

Just `en.XYZ.com/Account/Login` or for example `de.XYZ.com/SomeController/SomeAction` (subdomain switch the language variable - that is more friendly for SEO)

How to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

is there any reason why you are using the session variable? a more common solution is to include the language code in the route, i.e. blah.com/en/info or blah.com/jp/info (for english and japanese)

if you did this every page on the site could contain links to each language. if you are writing a publicly accessible site this would also make it easier for google to index all your content.

this article explains how to include the language in the domain, ie. en.blah.com or jp.blah.com: http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/05/20/ASPNET-MVC-Domain-Routing.aspx

UPDATED: Here's a simple example of including the language code in the URL route.

Change the default route to include a language parameter:

```
routes.MapRoute(
"Default", 
"{language}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
new { language = "en", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
);
Add links for each language to your masterpage:

<li>@Html.ActionLink(
    "Spanish", 
    ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString(), 
    new { language = "es" })</li>
```

These will render as links back to the page you are on - only with the language changed.